# Keypoint response() method

Tags: opencv, javacv

I've successfully used the response() method to order the keypoints in my Image Retrieval software, and I can clearly see the advantage it brings. I'm having a bit of trouble though trying to figure out the science behind it, since the documentation only says that the method lets you know how strong or a weak a given keypoint is.

I'd like to know how it actually works, because I like to understand how things operate in the backstage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333506/59184), but in essence it's the response of the blob detection step which generated this feature point. So when the algorithm finds areas of the image which are interesting, it's the measure of how much the blob looks like a blob.