# OpenCV Keypoints response, greater or less?

Tags: c++, opencv, keypoint

According to OpenCV [KeyPoint](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/features2d/KeyPoint.html) documentation, there is `response` field in every keypoints that:

> float response: The response, by which the strongest keypoints have been selected.

But I couldn't find whether the greater response is better or less? I want to sort the keypoints and pick only the best 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, `response` is indeed an indicator of *"how good"* (roughly speaking, in terms of corner-ness) a point is. The higher, the better. The strongest keypoints means the ones that are the best.

You can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10328298/2589776) for more info and examples.

Comment: It is represented as a floating point number. You mean, for instance, `0.87` is better than `0.76`?

Comment: @MikaelS. Yes, the higher, the better.